# A system of equations of Vietnamese Mathematical Olympiad 2013

Tags: problem-solving

This is a system of equation of Vietnamese Mathematical Olympiad 2013, the first day. Solve the system of equations
$$\begin{cases}
\sqrt{\sin^2 x + \dfrac{1}{\sin^2 x}} + \sqrt{\cos^2 y + \dfrac{1}{\cos^2 y}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{20y}{x+y}},\\
\sqrt{\sin^2 y + \dfrac{1}{\sin^2 y}} + \sqrt{\cos^2 x + \dfrac{1}{\cos^2 x}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{20x}{x+y}}.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Hint: add the equations and show that $\sqrt{\sin^2 x + \dfrac{1}{\sin^2 x}} + \sqrt{\cos^2 x + \dfrac{1}{\cos^2 x}}$ is minimized when $\sin^2 x = \cos^2 x = 1/2$. The rest is easy.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17621/how-to-solve-a-system-of-equations-of-the-vietnamese-mathematical-olympiad.