# System with sin and cos

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

How to solve the following system of equations if $x,y>0$?

$\begin{cases}
\sqrt{\sin^{2}x+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}x}}+\sqrt{\cos^{2}y+\frac{1}{\cos^{2}y}}=\sqrt{\frac{20y}{x+y}} \newline
\sqrt{\sin^{2}y+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}y}}+\sqrt{\cos^{2}x+\frac{1}{\cos^{2}x}}=\sqrt{\frac{20x}{x+y}}
\end{cases}$

I tried graphing this with Desmos and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQgNQ.png) is what I got.

If I square both the equations I would get

$\begin{cases}
\sqrt{\sin^{2}x+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}x}}+\sqrt{\cos^{2}y+\frac{1}{\cos^{2}y}}=\sqrt{\frac{20y}{x+y}}|()^2 \newline
\sqrt{\sin^{2}y+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}y}}+\sqrt{\cos^{2}x+\frac{1}{\cos^{2}x}}=\sqrt{\frac{20x}{x+y}}|()^2 
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
\sin^{2}x+\cos^{2}y+\frac{1}{\cos^{2}y}+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}x}+2\sqrt{\sin^{2}x+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}x}}\sqrt{\cos^{2}y+\frac{1}{\cos^{2}y}}=\frac{20y}{x+y}\newline
\sin^{2}y+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}y}+\cos^{2}x+\frac{1}{\cos^{2}x}+2\sqrt{\sin^{2}y+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}y}}\sqrt{\cos^{2}x+\frac{1}{\cos^{2}x}}=\frac{20x}{x+y}
\end{cases}$

I don't think this will help in solving the system.

What should I do next?

Comment: Duplicate of [MSE Q275874](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275874/). Since there's no posted answer yet on the former, the question can't be closed, but Whuber's comment gives a sufficient hint for solving it. Sum the two equations, observe the symmetry in univariate functions, then minimize them.

Comment: For your last set of equations, try subtracting them.